# Fetch 2 last messages from a specific user discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to fetch the last 2 messages someone sent but I couldn't find how. I tried:

```
console.log(user.lastMessage) // to get the last one since i was desperate, i also tried lastMessageId
```

and

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch({ author: message.author}).then(async (messages) => {
     console.log(messages.first(2)[1].content)
})
```

The first method would return undefined.
The second method also returned messages from other users.

This is for my ranking system, I want to add a 15 seconds cooldown between each messages added to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`message.channel.messages.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) you are getting a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection) with all the messages in the channel up to a certain point. But the thing is that, the [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection) is in reverse which means that the newest messages are in the first while the older ones are at the end. So you just have to perform a [`.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) function to see the first message where the author was a specific person. An example would look like this =>

```js
const messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch()
const userLastMessage = messages.find(msg => msg.author.id === message.author.id)
```

To get the second last item in the [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection), you would have to change the code a little bit since the [`.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) function returns the first one which matches the criteria. So you can change that to the [`.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) function. Then you can use [`.last()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=last) and then pass the number '2' into it. This will get you the two last items in the [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection). Then you can just get the second element in the array. An example =>

```js
const messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch()
const allMessagesPostedByUser = messages.filter(msg => msg.author.id === message.author.id)
const lastTwoMessages = allMessagesPostedByUser.last(2)
const secondLastMessage = allMessagesPostedByUser.last(2)[1]
```

Comment: That works really well! Although it returns the latest message and I'm looking for the latest message before that one. How do I get the one before the latest? Sorry about the dumb questions, I barely have any knowledge on maps.

Answer (score 2):

Fetching is absolutely not the way to do what you want to do, since you would fetch messages every single time someone sends a message. On top of that, there is actually no way to fetch messages from only one member (not user, users aren't members). The question then is: what happens if someone did not send a message in past 100 messages? Do you fetch another 100? What if they didn't speak in this channel yet or even never sent a message in the server before?

The correct way to do this is to store a timestamp of when someone sent a message, and when they send another message, compare it to your stored value to check if enough time has passed since the previous message.

Comment: Hm, that looks like a good idea. I'll try it out later.